# Обновление страницы, если пользователь вернулся по кнопке "Назад"

Tags: php

Добрый день. Имею следующую проблему:

1. Человек забивает N количество полей.
2. В случае успешной валидации человека перекидывает на платежку, пусть это будет PayPal. В этот момент у юзера создается аккаунт, и он автоматически становиться авторизованным.
3. Если человек передумал платить на PayPal'e, он нажимает кнопку "Назад" в своем браузере и видит опять те же поля, которые он заполнял ранее.

Хотя если нажать F5, то все, что нужно заполнять, схлопывается...

Кто знает, как решить данную проблему и может хоть как-то отправить в нужном направлении? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.Перекидывает на ту же страницу и только затем на палку. Если с нее спиной вернется - то уже ту страницу, на которую перекидывали в начале ответа. Типовая схема.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно отправлять данные из формы на другую страницу, там их обработать и вернуть браузер к предыдущей странице.